# Store Temporary Data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

SO i have chat box where in user can chat. But the problem is when user refresh all previous data is lost.

So is there a way i can store all data entered in textarea havind id `'chat-box-textinput'` and show it back even on refresh.

```
 function chatRefreshState(state) {
            if (state) {
                $('#chat-box-header').text(options.onlineTitle);
                if (!requestChat) {
                    $('#chat-box').html(
                        '<div id="chat-box-msg" style="height:225px;overflow:auto;">' +
                        '<p>Have a question? Let\'s chat!</p><p>Enter your Name & Question in the field\'s below and press ENTER.</p>' +
                        '<p style="margin-top:10px;">Enter Your Name</p><input type="text" id="chat-box-name" style="border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;width: 100%;height:30px;" class="chat-editing" /></div>' +
                        '<div id="chat-box-input" ><textarea id="chat-box-textinput" style="width:100%;height:45px;border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;" /></div>'
                    );
                }
            } else {
                if (!chatEditing) {
                    $('#chat-box-header').text(options.offlineTitle);
                    $('#chat-box-input').hide();
                    $('#chat-box').html(
                        '<p>Your email</p><input type="text" id="chat-box-email" style="border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;width: 100%;" class="chat-editing" />' +
                        '<p>Your message</p><textarea id="chat-box-cmt" cols="40" rows="7" class="chat-editing" style="border:1px solid #0354cb;border-radius: 3px;"></textarea>' +
                        '<p><input type="button" id="chat-box-send" value="Contact us" />'
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why downvotes??? If it sounds foolish please ignore instead of downvoting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try html5 storage or use jquery plugin

> With HTML5, web pages can store data locally within the user's browser.

REFERENCE
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

jStorage => http://www.jstorage.info/

jquery-total-storage =>
 https://github.com/Upstatement/jquery-total-storage
Usefull link

http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/storage/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but it depends on your browser support.

```
 window.localStorage.setItem("testdata","yes you are");

 window.localStorage.getItem("testdata");
```